# The last place in this category is the Netherlands with almost twice less car use

Tags: writing, ielts, academic-writing

There is an IELTS writing task:
[image]

[image]

Is this description correct?

> According to the table, it is clearly seen that car use prevails in
> all represented countries. **The leader in the group** is Canada with 90
> percent of journeys made by cars. **The last place in this category**
> is the Netherlands with almost **twice less** car use.

I'm particularly interested in the phrases in bold.
Is it ok to say 'the leader in the group'?
'The last place in this category is...'?
'Twice less' definitely sounds odd, but I'm not sure how to rephrase it.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: The expression "twice less" is confusing to me. Better to say "half". Here you could say "slightly more than half" or "about half".

Comment: @David42 thank you for your answer! Do you mean it's better to say, 'The last place in this category is the Netherlands with about half car use'?

Comment: Yes, but you would use the definite article: "the Netherlands with about half the car use". It is definite because it refers to the level of car use in Canada. I'm also not sure whether you you really mean to say that these four countries are joined in a group or category. If not, if they have been selected arbitrarily, then it would be better to say "The leader among these countries..."

Comment: @David42 thank you! I thought so too. Your answer was really helpful. Could you, please, tell me if it's wrong to say 'almost half the car use'?

Comment: Using 'almost' does not tell the reader whether The Netherlands has less or more than half the car use of other countries. Usually, 'almost' means 'almost as much as' but from the table, they have *more than* half the use by citizens of any of the other countries. So The Netherlands has only a little more than half the car use of Canadians.

Comment: People don't really say "twice less than" (something) when they mean 50 percent, or half (something), etc, If something is 'almost half' of something else, I would definitely say it is less than 50 percent.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you for the explanation, but I'm a little bit confused. I thought 'about' and 'almost' mean more or less the same. What is the difference between them?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thank you very much for chipping in (is it ok to say that? :)).

Comment: @i_yre_b - we use almost to mean 'very nearly' or 'not quite' but still 'less than'. 49 is almost 50. 'About' means something different - 'a little more or less'. 49 and 51 are both about 50.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thank you. It makes sense.

Comment: Saying 'about half' means 'approximately half'. Suppose you are doing a job, saying "I am almost half way there" means *less than* 50% completed. Saying "I am about half way there" means more or less than 50%, aproximately 50%. True, your "almost the same" and "about the same" have similar meaning, but in respect of quantities there is a distinct difference.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you!

Comment: Also if 100 were reduced by 'almost half' the result would be _more than_ 50, while almost half of 100 is _less than_ 50.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey sorry, I didn't get that. Could you, please, specify what you meant?

Comment: @i_yre_b suppose I have $100 and you steal $49 from me. My wealth has gone down by nearly half, not more than half.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “twice less” should be “half.”

Other than that, it is grammatical, but I’m not sure if it says what you meant to say.

Saying “the leader” and “last place” makes it sound like Canada is winning and the Netherlands is losing - which implies that you are strongly in favor of car use. It is proper English but it conveys a judgment or opinion, which might not be what you intended.

More neutral language would be to simply say “Canada has the highest car usage” and “The Netherlands has the lowest.”

Comment: Thank you, SegNerd! I thought so too!